# Getting error with Oracle 11g CDC in StreamSets

Tags: streamsets, oracle-cdc

```
com.streamsets.datacollector.util.PipelineException: PREVIEW_0003 - Encountered error while previewing : com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_87 - Interrupted while waiting to read data
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.preview.sync.SyncPreviewer.start(SyncPreviewer.java:233)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.preview.async.AsyncPreviewer.lambda$start$0(AsyncPreviewer.java:94)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:226)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:222)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:226)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.metrics.MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService$MetricsTask.run(MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_87 - Interrupted while waiting to read data
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.jdbc.cdc.oracle.OracleCDCSource.produce(OracleCDCSource.java:320)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.configurablestage.DSource.produce(DSource.java:38)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.lambda$execute$2(StageRuntime.java:242)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:195)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:257)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StagePipe.process(StagePipe.java:219)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipelineRunner.runPollSource(PreviewPipelineRunner.java:310)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipelineRunner.run(PreviewPipelineRunner.java:209)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:522)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipeline.run(PreviewPipeline.java:51)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.preview.sync.SyncPreviewer.start(SyncPreviewer.java:214)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.jdbc.cdc.oracle.OracleCDCSource.produce(OracleCDCSource.java:306)
    ... 24 more
```

Pipeline i build is simple reading from ORACLE and writing in to Directory to evaluate the flexibility of Streamsets CDC support.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the preview timed out before the batch of data was processed. You can increase the timeout in the preview dialog. You may have to set the timeout quite high, depending on how fast the origin can assemble the required data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i will try with suggested changes.